# JBOSS AS 7 Load Balancing with Server Failover

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, failover

I have 2 instances of Jboss servers running on eg: 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2.

I have implemented Jboss load balancing, but am not sure how to achieve server failover. I do not have a webserver to monitor the heartbeat and hence using mod_cluster is out the question. Is there any way I can achieve failover using only the two available servers?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JBoss clustering](http://www.jboss.org/jbossclustering) automatically provides JNDI and EJB failover and also HTTP session replication.

If your JBoss AS nodes are in a cluster then the failover should just work.

The [Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/cluster_guide/5.1/html/index.html) refers to an older version of JBoss (5.1) but it has clear descriptions of how JBoss clustering works.

Answer (score 0):

You could spun up another instance to server as your domain controller, and the two instances you already have will be your hosts. Then you could go through the domain controller, and it will do the work for you. However, I haven't seen instances going down to often, it usually servers that do, and it looks like you are using just one server (i might be wrong) for both instances, so i would consider splitting it up.

Comment: I have 2 seperate servers (2 different URL's) with an instance of JBOSS running on each server. I have configured a domain controller in one and host in the other. My requirement however, is for failover to occur seamlessly over the servers using only a single URL. Implementing Apache mod_cluster works fine IF one of the Jboss instance's is down, but will fail if the server itself goes down.  I am looking for a solution that can handle server failure as well as JBOSS failure.  Possibly a configuration in the IP routers???[guessing!!]